# Lines running down screen of iPod touch 4th generation

Tags: ipod-touch, graphics, screen

It's almost like stuck pixels- except they're moving down the screen...? Recently, after turning on a 4th generation iPod touch for the first time in two or three months, I noticed that lines were running down the screen!  Rebooting is not helping. <s>Is a restore recommended for this kind of situation? Is it a hardware or a software issue? With iOS 6 due in less than a week, should updating fix this problem?</s> How exactly did this happen to the hardware? Would [replacing the screen](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Front-Panel-Replacement/3639/1) resolve this issue, or would the problem lie deeper in the hardware?

**edit** restoring did not help; the lines were shown even when booting at the Apple logo and when showing the 'connect to iTunes' image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display is dying. Replace the display or buy a new iPod touch.

Comment: Would [this guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Front-Panel-Replacement/3639/1) resolve the issue?

Comment: Yep, it will. But doing it yourself would set you back about $110.